# Can I use WCF for communicating (sending message) between 2 applications?

Tags: wcf

I have a problem regarding WCF .Can i do that:-

I want to create WCF service,window service & Silverlight Application.And I want to send message(data) from  window service to silverlight application through wcf service.

and vice-versa.Is it possible.

Thanks & Regards,

Vipin Kumar

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible, if the receiving side has a listener that listen for messages then reply as needed to those messages. I think what you are really looking for is a Pub/Sub solution to communicated between two different processes.